# JQuery: Trying to add custom validation to UF Validator

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am using the [UF Validator](http://labs.utopicfarm.com/ufvalidator/) on a project and I'd like to add some custom validation checks.

I want to add a username check that gives an error if the input contains anything other than a-z 0-9. No spaces or anything. Similarly I want to add a name check that only allows a-z, but does allow spaces.

I am basing my checks on the built in email validation. Here is the filter:

```
var mail_filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
```

And here is the code for the email check:

```
// E-MAIL VALIDATION
    if (obj.hasClass('req-email')) {
        tmpresult = mail_filter.test(valAttr);
        if (!tmpresult) errorTxt = (valAttr == '') ? opts.errorMsg.reqMailEmpty : opts.errorMsg.reqMailNotValid;
        result = result && tmpresult;
    }
```

And here are my filters:

```
var username_filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]/;
var name_filter = /^[a-zA-Z ]/;
```

And here is my code:

```
// USERNAME VALIDATION
    if (obj.hasClass('req-username')) {
        tmpresult = username_filter.test(valAttr);
        if (!tmpresult) errorTxt = (valAttr == '') ? opts.errorMsg.reqUsernameEmpty : opts.errorMsg.reqUsernameNotValid;
        result = result && tmpresult;
    }
// NAME VALIDATION
    if (obj.hasClass('req-name')) {
        tmpresult = name_filter.test(valAttr);
        if (!tmpresult) errorTxt = (valAttr == '') ? opts.errorMsg.reqNameEmpty : opts.errorMsg.reqNameNotValid;
        result = result && tmpresult;
    }
```

I have referenced them here as well:

```
// gather inputs & check is valid
    $(merged_options.scope+' .req-email, '+merged_options.scope+' .req-string, '+merged_options.scope+' .req-same, '+merged_options.scope+' .req-both, '+merged_options.scope+' .req-numeric, '+merged_options.scope+' .req-date, '+merged_options.scope+' .req-min, '+merged_options.scope+' .req-username, '+merged_options.scope+' .req-name').each(function() {
        thisValid = $.formValidator.validate($(this),merged_options);
        boolValid = boolValid && thisValid.error;
        if (!thisValid.error) errorMsg  = thisValid.message;
    });
```

The corresponding error messages exist as well but I don't think they need showing.

I thought this would work fine but when I try, it behaves quite strangely. Showing the wrong error messages and not validating it how I want it to. I've checked their website and searched on here but can't find anything relating to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex only test for the presence of a single character at the start of the string.
You need to add a `+` to indicate that you want to match *one or more* characters, e.g. `[a-z\d]+`, or you can specify a range.

For example, the regex below specify that the strings must be between 1 and 20 characters long.

```
var username_filter = /^[a-z\d]{1,20}$/i;
var name_filter = /^[a-z ]{1,20}$/i;
```

The end character `$` is needed, or you are only specifying what must be at the start of the string.

The `i` flag means a case-insensitive match, assuming that is what you want;  `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`.